# How to extract only july-month of a time series running from 1985-2018 (txt file)

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have a .txt_file showing dates and runoff from 1985-2018 for one station in Norway. 
I need to make a plot of the runoff in all July-months. 
Here is my code:

```
from pandas import read_csv

import numpy as np

import pandas as pd

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import os

import cartopy

from datetime import date,datetime

dir1 = "mystations/"

files = os.listdir(dir1)

files = np.sort(files)

files_txt = [i for i in files if i.endswith('.txt_')]

df = pd.read_csv(dir1+files_txt[0],skiprows=6,header=None, index_col=0,sep=" ",na_values=-9999, parse_dates = True)

df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index,format="%Y%m%d/%H%M")

myperiod = df["1985":"2018"]

myperiod
```

and my code prints out a table with the dates and the following runoff values for all years and all months.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q6qrS.png)

How do I plot only runoff for July-month?

Comment: Hello! you could try finding all those indexes such that the month is equal to 7 (july). Since what you get is a datetime, I think this should work: `df[df.index.month == 7]` to filter all the data that you need.

Comment: okey thank you, it worked. But now it read all July months from 1921-2019, how do I get it to read all July months from 1985-2018?

Comment: Hi Madelen, that code is supposed to filter all July months in your dataset, so I guess that the data you are working on goes from 1921 to 2019. Can you print `pd.to_datetime(df.index,format="%Y%m%d/%H%M").min()` and `pd.to_datetime(df.index,format="%Y%m%d/%H%M").max()` ? :)

Comment: Glad to help you!